# Why the added prototype method should be added after `util.inherits`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know why the added `prototype method` should be added after `util.inherits`?

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Server() {
    console.log('init');
}

Server.prototype.say = function(){
    console.log('say');
}

util.inherits(Server, EventEmitter);

var server = new Server();
server.on('abc', function(){
    console.log('abc');
})

server.emit('abc');
server.say();
```

There is an error when i run this code:

```
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.js:19
server.say();
       ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.js:19:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

But if i modified code to this:

```
util.inherits(Server, EventEmitter);

Server.prototype.say = function(){
    console.log('say');
}
```

the code runs ok.

Comment: In all likelyhood, the util.inherits will overwrite the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the node.js documentation https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor:

> *util.inherits(constructor, superConstructor)*
>
> Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another. **The prototype of constructor will be set to a new object created from superConstructor**.

So basically after you use util.inherits on Server, its prototype is replaced by new, inheriting from EventEmitter, hence previously added methods are lost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Where can i find the source code of `util.inherits(constructor, superConstructor)`.